# Using HDPARM to tune drives

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance-tuning, hdparm

Can HDPARM reallt be used to tune and enhance performance on drives? I've seen tutorials but does it really make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There once was a time when it made a big difference. But on modern hardware, the drivers pick the optimal settings anyway, so there's usually nothing to tune.

Comment: That is what I was thinking and figured.